# make a list from string json? python

Tags: python

I have a json string  i get it from json array below i have given it

```
annotation = sentence["annotation"]
text = sentence["text"]
#ioblist = [annotation]
ioblist=[[x[0], x[4]] for x in annotation]  #nothing
```

the proram did not convert here is my string in list at index 0

```
   {u'1': [u'Bill', u'bill', u'NNP', u'B-PERSON'], 
   u'3': [u'born', u'bear', u'VBN', u'O'], 
   u'2': [u'was', u'be', u'VBD', u'O'], 
   u'5':  [u'.', u'.', u'.', u'O'], 
   u'4': [u'1986', u'BIL', u'CD', u'B-DATE']}
```

**update 1:**

I am making list as

```
 ioblist=[[x[0], x[4]] for x in annotation]
```

Comment: Can you please show a sample of the data you are inputting in to your code to have a better understanding? Could you also show what the output should look like?

Comment: NOW CHECK WHERE THE PROB ORIGINATE

Answer (score 0):

`range()` gives you a iterable of integers, but your dictionary keys are `u'...'`, i.e. unicode strings. Hence, the lookup `ioblist[0]` must fail, since `0 != u'0'` (Python isn't PHP, thankfully).